# Add Items in a listview to another Activity

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I have create a custom listview. I want to add items to my listview From a secondActivity in MainActivity even my Activity isnt open. And when my Mainactivity(with listview) will be open too show me what  i have add in it.

**This is my First class code:**

```
 class TableItemsClass
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public string ItemPrice { get; set; }
    public string TotalPrice { get; set; }

}
```

**My second class**

```
   class MyListViewAdapter : BaseAdapter<TableItemsClass>
{
    public List<TableItemsClass> mitems;
    private Context mContext;
    public MyListViewAdapter(Context context, List<TableItemsClass> items)
    {
        mitems = items;
        mContext = context;

    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return mitems.Count;
        }
    }
    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public override TableItemsClass this[int position]
    {
        get
        {
            return mitems[position];
        }

    }
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null)
        {
            row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.TableItems, null, false);

        }
        TextView txtDescription = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtDescription);
        txtDescription.Text = mitems[position].Description;


        TextView txtQuantity = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtQuantity);
        txtQuantity.Text = mitems[position].Quantity;

        TextView txtItemPrice = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtItemPrice);
        txtItemPrice.Text = mitems[position].ItemPrice;

        TextView txtTotalPrice = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtTotalPrice);
        txtTotalPrice.Text = mitems[position].TotalPrice;



        return row;
    }
}
```

}

So i'm using thus code in a second activity for adding an extra item to my listview in Main Activity.But unfortunately it doesnt add anything.

```
   private List<TableItemsClass> mItems;
    private ListView mlistview;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);



        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.TableItemsMain);
        mlistview = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);

        mItems = new List<TableItemsClass>();

        mItems.Add(new TableItemsClass() { Description = "test", Quantity = "3", ItemPrice = "2.00", TotalPrice = "6.00" });

        MyListViewAdapter adapter = new MyListViewAdapter(this, mItems);


        mlistview.Adapter = adapter;
```

Comment: there are several solutions. tell me more about your situation then i will suggest one solution with complete code

    1. pass data from activity to ListView activity with Intent
    2. save data (in file, SharedPref, sqlite) in second activity and reload listview 
    3. save data (in static variable) in second activity and reload listview

Comment: I thing that the best idea is if i could add items from listview with intent. And when opening my MainActivity to shows me all items i have add the in intent.Thank You

Comment: so use this intent.putExtra("key", String[] items);

Comment: Is this method flexible?I mean can i delete one item from my data?

Answer (score 0):

Try `LocalBroadcastReceiver` to fix your problem. Here is how can you use in your case -

Put this code in your receiver `activity`, i.e. `MainActivity`

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Get extra data included in the Intent
    TableItemsClass message = intent.getSerializableExtra("message");
    // Add this data into your list dataset... Later on you can update your
    // `onResume()` to update data...
  }
};
```

Register receiver into your `oncreate()`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  ...

  // Register to receive messages.
  // We are registering an observer (mMessageReceiver) to receive Intents
  // with actions named "custom-event-name".
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
      new IntentFilter("custom-event-name"));
}
```

Don't forget to destroy your `receiver` -

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
  // Unregister since the activity is about to be closed.
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
  super.onDestroy();
}
```

Do this code in your sender `activity`, i.e. `SecondActivity`

```
// Send an Intent with an action named "custom-event-name". The Intent sent should 
// be received by the ReceiverActivity.
private void sendMessage() {
  Intent intent = new Intent("custom-event-name");
  // You can also include some extra data.
  intent.putExtra("message", "your model to be put in receiver's listview");
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```